# Is CoffeeScript converting the code wrong?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, coffeescript

I am using Mongoose + CoffeeScript and when I try to add embedded documents to my Schema, the code is wrongly converted.

e.g:

```
AccountSchema = new Schema # Companhia
    name : String
    users  : [UserSchema]
    custphones  : [CustphoneSchema]
```

becomes

```
AccountSchema = new Schema({
    name: String({
      users: [UserSchema],
      custphones: [CustphoneSchema]
    })
  });
```

and should have become

```
AccountSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    users: [UserSchema],
    custphones: [CustphoneSchema]
 });
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check that the indentations are consistent in their use of tabs and spaces? This is a common problem when whitespace is part of the syntax.

To get your your particular (broken) output, you probably indented with tab on `name`, and spaces on `users` and `custphones`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles correctly on my machine. What you still can do is to add commas to the hash entries to help coffee script compile your code:

```
AccountSchema = new Schema # Companhia
    name : String,
    users  : [UserSchema],
    custphones  : [CustphoneSchema]
```